# How to reset position on all keyframes?

Tags: animation

I need to reset the position of some bones in an animation, how do i do it to all keyframes at one?

Trying to port a model to a game, I used the bones from other model and because my model is shorter, I adjust some bone positions to match the model. Now i imported animations the legs and some other part are stretched, so i need to reset position on those bones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In pose mode, select the bones you wish to reset.  Use a "hide selected" operation (shift h for me) to hide all other bones.
2. Open a graph editor view.  Make sure "only show selected" is enabled, in the upper right corner of the graph editor.  Click on the "filters" button and enter "location" (no quotes) in the "f-curve name filter" field, which has a magnifying glass icon in it.
3. Now you only have location keyframes of your selected bones.  In graph editor, select all and delete.
4. In 3D window, use a "clear pose location" operation (alt g for me.)
5. Optionally, keyframe at the beginning and end of your animation.